# Residual error in infinity norm: Approximate within 8 decimal places in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, iteration

I am writing a program to solve a system of linear equations and need the approximation within 8 decimal places, using the residual error in infinity norm. My Matlab code for computing the residual error is given by:

```
norm(x-xj,inf)
```

Where `x` the true vector x in `Ax=b` and `xj` is the result of me applying the Jacobi iterative method to the system. I need to specify a residual error norm that this value described above in my Matlab code must be less than for my Jacobi method code to end (i.e. it must be within 8 decimal places of the true `x` vector which is known).

I've read through the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) on the infinity norm and understand the intuition, but I'm not sure how to write Matlab code to directly compute an acceptable range for `xj` that is within 8 decimal places of `x` (based on the infinity norm residual error).

Comment: Please provide an [***mcve***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have a much higher chance of getting a useful answer if you do. Your question if very abstract and other people can't play around with it on their own machines in order to help you. You haven't given much to go on I'm afraid.

Comment: Is there any reason that using `norm(x-xj,inf) < 1e-8` is not adequate?